# Entity Framework not updating entity when using Task.Factory

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda, task

I have Entity Framework code which is supposed to be updating an entity called `Asset`. For some reason, it's not updating as it should. Debugging to see the root cause of this issue is difficult as I don't see any exceptions.

The problem is in the repository class where it always returns an

> Asset could not be updated

message even if I pass in a valid `Book` or `Asset` object.

Model classes

```
public class Asset
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Book : Asset
{
    public string Isbn { get; set; }
    public string Edition { get; set; }
    public string  Publisher { get; set; }
    public virtual  User User { get; set; }
}
```

Controller class

```
[System.Web.Http.Authorize]
public async  Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromBody] BookViewModel model)
{
        string result = null;

        try
        {
            if (model.IsEmpty) 
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            result = await _assetAssetRepository.Update(Mapper.Map<Book>(model));
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.Created, result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, result);
        }
}
```

Repository class:

```
public class AssetRepository
{
     private readonly GenAppContext _context = new GenAppContext();

     public Task<string> Update(Asset asset)
     {
         try
         {
            var updateTask = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                if (!(asset is Book)) 
                    return "Please return correct type of asset";

                var _asset = _context.Assets.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == asset.Id);

                if (_asset == null) 
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_asset));

                _asset.Name = asset.Name;
                ((Book) _asset).Edition = ((Book) asset).Edition;
                ((Book) _asset).Publisher = ((Book) asset).Publisher;
                ((Book) _asset).Isbn = ((Book) asset).Isbn;

                _context.Assets.AddOrUpdate(_asset);

                return _context.SaveChanges() > 0
                    ? "Asset has been updated successfully"
                    : "Asset could not be updated";
            });

            return updateTask;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd start cleaning up. The method might as wel be `Update(Book book)`. This saves you all these casts (which you could do once anyway) and typos (`((Book)asset).Edition = ((Book)asset).Edition;`). Also, you don't need to set the state to `Modified` nor do you need `AddOrUpdate` (and you *certainly* don't need them both!). EF already tracks the changes. Then monitor the SQL statement(s) that `SaveChanges` executes.

Comment: Hi @GertArnold  i have fixed the typos. Thanks for your comment. I had only AddorUpdate before but it wasnt working so i added the line that sets the state to modified to see if its works

Comment: When is `_context` instantiated, and how?

Comment: There seems to be no reason not to make that method async and use await SingleOrDefaultAsync() and await SaveChangesAsync(), instead of Task.Factory.StartNew()

Comment: @Eris i have updated the repository class. Thanks

Comment: @sellotape thanks for the suggestion

Comment: This: "_context.Assets.AddOrUpdate(_asset);" makes little sense there.  You've already retrieved the Asset in _asset.  It's already attached to Assets in your _context.  EF automatically detects the change when you update it.  Just remove that line.